# Using Hive, how to query data that is split across multiple partitions?

Tags: hive

From a table partitioned over date field (a new partition is generated every day), I need to extract records that range over last three months. This means that I need to query the table on every partition in the last three months to get the data by using "where date < 'today's date' and date>= 'today - 90 days'.

I think that this query would not be very efficient. 
Is there a better way of accessing data that is spread across multiple partitions?

Comment: Why do you think it is inefficient?

Comment: The table has huge number of rows per partition and I want only a few of them from each partition (based on a matching criterion). So, searching over multiple partitions for few rows is where the query might become inefficient.

Comment: It all depends on your infrastructure. Your cluster must have sufficient datanodes to efficiently process your request. Your WHERE condition will still prune out a lot of partitions (3 months = about 90 partitions) out of many years (i assume).

Comment: Yes, I realized that the dataset is really huge and most likely I will be querying specific partitions to extract it since it is not partitioned on the key I am looking at.